# how to remove values of invisible fields in wizard openerp

Tags: dynamic, hide, wizard, odoo, invisible

I have a wizard with few fields. initially it only shows a selection fields and based on what is selected (i've used on_change), it would show other fields.

Now im having problem in this scenario. The user initially select 'select 1' and shows (lets say) name, address, age and gives value to this field, but the user decided to change the initial field to 'select 2' which will hide other fields and show field subject, time, instructor. but when i try to select 'select 1' again, the values are not removed.

I want to remove the existing values of the hidden fields.

Do you have any idea on how to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: can you add the on change function here?

Comment: @AnomA I've put the on_change to answer as it doesn't fit in comment

Answer (score 1):

You ca create on_change method for the Selection type field.

In that method you can return '' values for fields according to the selection field value.

```
i.e if select=1 then return {'value':{'subject':'', 'time':'' , 'instructure': False}}
& if select=2 then return {'value':{'name':'', address:'' , 'age': 0}}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: yeah, but the problem is that the fields on the wizard are dynamic where fields of the wizard are defined as a record, meaning the record is defined (o2m) in the main form where wizard are being called. Since its that dynamic I can't just declare the field names in the dictionary.

But, thanks. I will look into this.

Comment: @Lafada: Ahi to picho chod , navro thai gayo che k su ?;)

Comment: Le ame kya picho kariaa chia aa to tari comment joi atle am thayu ke tane kai dua :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_status_reason(self, cr, uid, field_val, question_id, status_reason_id=False):
    pool = self.pool.get
    question_obj = pool('jfs.question.template.answer').read(cr, uid, question_id, ['name', 'status_reason_id','question_template_ids'])
    if str(question_obj['name']) != field_val:
        for child_question in question_obj['question_template_ids']:
            status_reason_id = self.get_status_reason(cr, uid, field_val, child_question, status_reason_id)
    else:
        if question_obj['status_reason_id']:
            status_reason_id = question_obj['status_reason_id'][0]
        else:
            status_reason_id = False
    return status_reason_id

def onchange_field_val(self, cr, uid, ids, field_val, task_id, status_reason_id):
    pool = self.pool.get
    task_obj = pool('aybabtu.task').read(cr, uid, task_id, ['question_set_id'])
    status_reason_id = self.get_status_reason(cr, uid, field_val, task_obj['question_set_id'][0], status_reason_id)
    res = {'status_reason_id':status_reason_id}
    #self.get_child_questions(cr, uid, field_val, task_id)
    return {'value':res}

def generate_xml(self, cr, uid, view_type, data, sorted_field_list, result, context):
    xml = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <%s>''' % (view_type)
    context_val = {}
    context_val['task_id'] = context['active_id']

    task_obj = self.pool.get('aybabtu.task').read(cr, uid, context_val['task_id'], ['state'])
    for field_name in sorted_field_list: 
        attribute = {}
        context_val[field_name] = str(field_name)
        #print "result['fields'][field_name]", result['fields'][field_name]
        if result['fields'][field_name]['context'] != 'none' and result['fields'][field_name]['context'] != 'task' and eval(result['fields'][field_name]['context'])[4] == 'required':
            require = 'required="1"'

        else:
            require = ''

        if result['fields'][field_name]['context'] != 'none' and result['fields'][field_name]['context'] != 'task' and eval(result['fields'][field_name]['context'])[7] and task_obj['state'] in ['done']:
            readonly = 'readonly="1"'
        else: readonly = ''

        if result['fields'][field_name]['context'] != 'none' and result['fields'][field_name]['context'] != 'task' and eval(result['fields'][field_name]['context'])[5] == 'widget':
            widget = 'widget="selection"'
            filter = "context=\"{'custom_domain_timeslot':[ticket_id,type_id,state]}\""

        else:
            widget = ''
            filter = ''

        if field_name == str(data['name']):
            xml += '''<field name="%s" select="1" required="1" nolabel="1" on_change="onchange_field_val(%s,task_id, status_reason_id)" colspan="4" sequence="1" %s/>''' % (field_name, field_name, readonly)

        elif result['fields'][field_name]['context'] == 'none':
            xml += '''<field name="%s"/>''' % (field_name)

        elif result['fields'][field_name]['context'] == 'task':
            xml += '''<field name="%s" invisible="1"/>''' % (field_name)

        else:
            attribute['invisible'] = [(eval(result['fields'][field_name]['context'])[2],'!=',eval(result['fields'][field_name]['context'])[1])]
            if require == 'required="1"':

                attribute['required'] = [(eval(result['fields'][field_name]['context'])[2],'=',eval(result['fields'][field_name]['context'])[1])]

            if result['fields'][field_name]['context'] != 'none' and result['fields'][field_name]['context'] != 'task' and eval(result['fields'][field_name]['context'])[5] == 'widget':
                filter_option = self.get_domain(cr, uid, context_val['task_id'], result['fields'][field_name]['context'])

            xml += '''<field name="%s" attrs="%s" colspan="4" on_change="onchange_field_val(%s,task_id, status_reason_id)" %s %s %s/>''' % (field_name, attribute, field_name, widget, filter, readonly)

    xml += '''<button name="question_save_task" string="Save and Close Task" colspan="4" type="object" icon="gtk-convert" context="%s"/>''' % (context_val)
    xml += '''</%s>''' % (view_type,)
    return xml
```

@anoma I also overload the field_view_get() that calls the generate_xml() where the field attribute for invisible is dynamic too